# Does the "overflow-y: scroll" property help prevent horizontal shift in Opera/Safari?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm using the following in my CSS to force a vertical scrollbar in Firefox:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Does this technique work in Safari and Opera?  Some people say it does and some say otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS rule `overflow-y: scroll` works for me in:

- Opera 10.10
- Google Chrome 3.0.195.38
- Mozilla Firefox 3.5.6

and obviously all versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer where the scrollbar is *always* shown.

Safari and Google Chrome are using the same view engine, so chances are it works in Safari as well :)

Comment: Thankyou very much, nice to know that it works in Chrome too - forgot about that one!  I can always test this out on a friends Mac but I'm fairly confident, from what you've said, that it will work fine.  Thanks again.

Comment: Note: IE8 and later do not show the vertical scroll bar. Atleast not within the standards compliance mode.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

works in Opera 11.01 and Safari 5.0.3 for Windows, but this:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

doesn't work in Opera and works for the rest.